# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket - Fedora

Tags: linux, permissions, mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I am a new Fedora user and I am installing ROR on my machine.

But when I try to enter the following command `rake db:create` it shows the following errors.

Can any one please tell me how can I solve this problem.

```
[smehsan@localhost proone]$ rake db:create
#<Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13 "Permission denied")>
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8",
"pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil,
"socket"=>"/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock",
"database"=>"proone_development"}, {:charset=>"utf8",
:collation=>"utf8_unicode_ci"}
(If you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching
collation)
#<Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13 "Permission denied")>
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8",
"pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil,
"socket"=>"/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock", "database"=>"proone_test"},
{:charset=>"utf8", :collation=>"utf8_unicode_ci"}
(If you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching
collation)
[smehsan@localhost proone]$
```

Comment: Have you got latest Fedora with all the updates? In Fedora, mysqld.sock is in `/var/lib/mysql` and not in `/var/run/mysqld`. It looks like you have mysql2 gem built for different mysql headers. So this means there's something wrong you did before with installing rails, gems and mysql servers and building them against wrong server configurations.

Comment: @AndrewSmith thank you.
Can you please tell me how can i fix this problem?

Comment: Nuke the `mysql2` gem and run `bundle install` again to rebuild it. If that doesn't help, look carefully at your MySQL server configuration.